# Using ajax/jQuery Form Validation on ASP.NET controls

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, jquery-validate

Good Day

I am using an ASP.NET page with a master page. I want to do live form validation on the input fields (). Now all the tuts and demos/plugins I have seen are using normal html labels. I tried to implement some of them on my form, but they are not working. (I am using a mater page and a normal aspx web form...)

UPDATE: Issue replacing input tags with asp controls for the password fields...

The original input elements

```
  <fieldset>
        <legend>Validating a complete form</legend>
        <p>
            <label for="firstname">Firstname</label>
            <input id="firstname" name="firstname" type="text" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="lastname">Lastname</label>
            <input id="lastname" name="lastname" type="text" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="username">Username</label>
            <input id="username" name="username" type="text" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input id="password" name="password" type="password" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="confirm_password">Confirm password</label>
            <input id="confirm_password" name="confirm_password" type="password" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input id="email" name="email" type="email" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="agree">Please agree to our policy</label>
            <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="agree" name="agree" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="newsletter">I'd like to receive the newsletter</label>
            <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="newsletter" name="newsletter" />
        </p>

        <tr>
            <td class="tdRight"><asp:Label ID="LabelEmail" runat="server" Text="Email Address (to be used as username):"></asp:Label></td>
            <td class="tdLeft"><asp:TextBox name="email" type="email" ID="TextBoxEmail" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" TextMode="SingleLine" MaxLength="50"></asp:TextBox></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="tdRight"><asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Postal Address:"></asp:Label></td>
            <td class="tdLeft"><asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxPostal" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="4" MaxLength="250"></asp:TextBox></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td class="tdRight"><asp:Label ID="LabelPassword" runat="server" Text="Password:"></asp:Label></td>
            <td class="tdLeft"><asp:TextBox name="password" type="password" ID="TextBoxPassword" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" TextMode="Password" MaxLength="50"></asp:TextBox></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="tdRight"><asp:Label ID="LabelConfirmPassword" runat="server" Text="Confirm Password:"></asp:Label></td>
            <td class="tdLeft"><asp:TextBox name="confirm_password" type="password" ID="TextBoxConfirmPassword" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" TextMode="Password" MaxLength="50"></asp:TextBox></td>
        </tr>

</fieldset>
```

I want to replace the above with the following ASP controls

```
        <tr>
            <td class="tdRight"><asp:Label ID="LabelEmail" runat="server" Text="Email Address (to be used as username):"></asp:Label></td>
            <td class="tdLeft"><asp:TextBox name="email" type="email" ID="TextBoxEmail" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" TextMode="SingleLine" MaxLength="50"></asp:TextBox></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="tdRight"><asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Postal Address:"></asp:Label></td>
            <td class="tdLeft"><asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxPostal" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="4" MaxLength="250"></asp:TextBox></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="tdRight"><asp:Label ID="LabelPassword" runat="server" Text="Password:"></asp:Label></td>
            <td class="tdLeft"><asp:TextBox name="password" type="password" ID="TextBoxPassword" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" TextMode="Password" MaxLength="50"></asp:TextBox></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="tdRight"><asp:Label ID="LabelConfirmPassword" runat="server" Text="Confirm Password:"></asp:Label></td>
            <td class="tdLeft"><asp:TextBox name="confirm_password" type="password" ID="TextBoxConfirmPassword" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" TextMode="Password" MaxLength="50"></asp:TextBox></td>
        </tr>
```

**Now everything works, except for the password fiels? Why? Also, ID's do not matter, as the the validator work on the name and type fields...**

jQuery:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $.validator.setDefaults({
            submitHandler: function () { alert("submitted!"); }
        });

        $().ready(function () {


            // validate signup form on keyup and submit
            $("form").validate({
                rules: {
                    firstname: "required",
                    lastname: "required",
                    username: {
                        required: true,
                        minlength: 2
                    },
                    password: {
                        required: true,
                        minlength: 5
                    },
                    confirm_password: {
                        required: true,
                        minlength: 5,
                        equalTo: "#password"
                    },
                    email: {
                        required: true,
                        email: true
                    },
                    topic: {
                        required: "#newsletter:checked",
                        minlength: 2
                    },
                    agree: "required"
                },
                messages: {
                    firstname: "Please enter your firstname",
                    lastname: "Please enter your lastname",
                    username: {
                        required: "Please enter a username",
                        minlength: "Your username must consist of at least 2 characters"
                    },
                    password: {
                        required: "Please provide a password",
                        minlength: "Your password must be at least 5 characters long"
                    },
                    confirm_password: {
                        required: "Please provide a password",
                        minlength: "Your password must be at least 5 characters long",
                        equalTo: "Please enter the same password as above"
                    },
                    email: "Please enter a valid email address",
                    agree: "Please accept our policy"
                }
            });

            // propose username by combining first- and lastname
            $("#username").focus(function () {
                var firstname = $("#firstname").val();
                var lastname = $("#lastname").val();
                if (firstname && lastname && !this.value) {
                    this.value = firstname + "." + lastname;
                }
            });

            //code to hide topic selection, disable for demo
            var newsletter = $("#newsletter");
            // newsletter topics are optional, hide at first
            var inital = newsletter.is(":checked");
            var topics = $("#newsletter_topics")[inital ? "removeClass" : "addClass"]("gray");
            var topicInputs = topics.find("input").attr("disabled", !inital);
            // show when newsletter is checked
            newsletter.click(function () {
                topics[this.checked ? "removeClass" : "addClass"]("gray");
                topicInputs.attr("disabled", !this.checked);
            });
        });
    </script>
```

**The REAL RENDERED HTML (pertaining the form)**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"
type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.validator.setDefaults({
        submitHandler: function() {
            alert("submitted!");
        }
    });

    $().ready(function() {


        // validate signup form on keyup and submit
        $("form").validate({
            rules: {
                firstname: "required",
                lastname: "required",
                username: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 2
                },
                password: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 5
                },
                confirm_password: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 5,
                    equalTo: "#password"
                },
                email: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                },
                topic: {
                    required: "#newsletter:checked",
                    minlength: 2
                },
                agree: "required"
            },
            messages: {
                firstname: "Please enter your firstname",
                lastname: "Please enter your lastname",
                username: {
                    required: "Please enter a username",
                    minlength: "Your username must consist of at least 2 characters"
                },
                password: {
                    required: "Please provide a password",
                    minlength: "Your password must be at least 5 characters long"
                },
                confirm_password: {
                    required: "Please provide a password",
                    minlength: "Your password must be at least 5 characters long",
                    equalTo: "Please enter the same password as above"
                },
                email: "Please enter a valid email address",
                agree: "Please accept our policy"
            }
        });

        // propose username by combining first- and lastname
        $("#username").focus(function() {
            var firstname = $("#firstname").val();
            var lastname = $("#lastname").val();
            if (firstname && lastname && !this.value) {
                this.value = firstname + "." + lastname;
            }
        });

        //code to hide topic selection, disable for demo
        var newsletter = $("#newsletter");
        // newsletter topics are optional, hide at first
        var inital = newsletter.is(":checked");
        var topics = $("#newsletter_topics")[inital ? "removeClass" : "addClass"]("gray");
        var topicInputs = topics.find("input").attr("disabled", !inital);
        // show when newsletter is checked
        newsletter.click(function() {
            topics[this.checked ? "removeClass" : "addClass"]("gray");
            topicInputs.attr("disabled", !this.checked);
        });
    });
</script>
<form method="get" action="SignupPersonal.aspx" id="aspnetForm"
class="cmxform">
    <div class="aspNetHidden">
        <input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwULLTIwMjk5MTc4MzEPZBYCZg9kFgICBQ9kFgICAQ9kFgICMA8QDxYGHg1EYXRhVGV4dEZpZWxkBQ9FbnVtRGVzY3JpcHRpb24eDkRhdGFWYWx1ZUZpZWxkBQlFbnVtVmFsdWUeC18hRGF0YUJvdW5kZ2QQFQMFRW1haWwlTm90aWZpY2F0aW9uIHZpYSBNb2JpbGUgVGV4dCBNZXNzYWdlcwRCb3RoFQMBMAExATIUKwMDZ2dnZGRksmDjLifKF4+hMs8AhfX/bwcgvt2QqQRuZWngXcH7AGM="
        />
    </div>
    <div class="aspNetHidden">
        <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="/wEdABBfr2cGXQNKgk5u/suiS/eBMBPtPHD3IbRvk+yxeYb2457gKW6aCQ3yNBTG9LyKZ4cubOXF5tOYlsiIBcyrDbyQ4wKHhHIVKN2DCQeFUhf9fWAUCuZOob8WzLZCHNXad+6lH/vCaPfCLoThuEr+9Jzl6wAt6cuJ+L+27/Nrmm6upAz//swWW9Bijj8L66VLU8Xqa57A90pLu4vVlIQKRMNCPMnVTRV7QuT7xghzXApY9g0EIzfFocd5Qmeb8RCzKLnYNu/sHr3w5Hv9l1IOx6mNGOqE5LWQWcaFAwIxNHVtD2pkSrWzz9gkUQepnHOZG7M83cV/FFqhRADq7X7PITxLg4JwtYX8Yw9N8ZivtSz9f1K3117QXOtSn4MTHtKkNBE="
        />
    </div>
    <div id="signupPersonal">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td class="tdRight"><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_LabelName">Name:</span>

                </td>
                <td class="tdLeft">
                    <input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$TextBoxName" type="text" maxlength="50"
                    id="TextBoxName" name="firstname" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="tdRight"><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_LabelSurname">Surname:</span>

                </td>
                <td class="tdLeft">
                    <input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$TextBoxSurname" type="text" maxlength="50"
                    id="TextBoxSurname" class="required" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="tdRight"><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_LabelPin">Preferred Pin:</span>

                </td>
                <td class="tdLeft">
                    <input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$TextBoxPin" type="password" maxlength="10"
                    id="TextBoxPin" class="required" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="tdRight"><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_LabelConfirmPin">Confirm Pin:</span>

                </td>
                <td class="tdLeft">
                    <input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$TextBoxConfirmPin" type="password"
                    maxlength="10" id="TextBoxConfirmPin" class="required" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="tdRight"><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_LabelPhoneNo">Home Number:</span>

                </td>
                <td class="tdLeft">
                    <input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$TextBoxPhoneNo" type="text" maxlength="20"
                    id="TextBoxPhoneNo" class="required digits" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="tdRight"><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_LabelMobileNo">Cell Number:</span>

                </td>
                <td class="tdLeft">
                    <input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$TextBoxMobileNo" type="text" maxlength="20"
                    id="TextBoxMobileNo" class="required digits" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="tdRight"><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_LabelIDNumber">ID Number:</span>

                </td>
                <td class="tdLeft">
                    <input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$TextBoxIDNumber" type="text" maxlength="20"
                    id="TextBoxIDNumber" class="required digits" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="tdRight"><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_LabelEmail">Email Address (to be used as username):</span>

                </td>
                <td class="tdLeft">
                    <input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$TextBoxEmail" maxlength="50" id="TextBoxEmail"
                    name="email" type="email" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="tdRight"><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Label1">Postal Address:</span>

                </td>
                <td class="tdLeft">
                    <textarea name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$TextBoxPostal" rows="4" cols="20"
                    id="TextBoxPostal"></textarea>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="tdRight"><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_LabelPassword">Password:</span>

                </td>
                <td class="tdLeft">
                    <input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$TextBoxPassword" maxlength="50"
                    id="TextBoxPassword" name="password" type="password" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="tdRight"><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_LabelConfirmPassword">Confirm Password:</span>

                </td>
                <td class="tdLeft">
                    <input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$TextBoxConfirmPassword" maxlength="50"
                    id="TextBoxConfirmPassword" name="confirm_password" type="password" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="tdRight"><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_LabelContactMethod">Preferred method of contact:</span>

                </td>
                <td class="tdLeft">
                    <select name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$DropDownListContactMethod" id="DropDownListContactMethod">
                        <option value="0">Email</option>
                        <option value="1">Notification via Mobile Text Messages</option>
                        <option value="2">Both</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <input type="submit" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ButtonRegister" value="Register"
                    id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ButtonRegister" class="register" class="submit"
                    type="submit" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you please show this validate() function?

Comment: ok, will update my answer...

Comment: What, exactly, does not work with password fields?

Comment: the validation. There is no validation. When you click on the <input/> password field and enter a single digit or whatever, the form tells you that the password length is too short etc etc. But when implementing it on the ASP password controls, it does not work - so you can type in anything there, even nothing, and it does not validate. But what bothers me is that this only happens for the password asp controls, and not the other ones(email, etc)

Comment: Interesting. Can you include generated html for the form? I wonder if ASP.NET doing something strange for password fields.

Comment: you mean generated from the browser?

Comment: Yes, the source that you see in the browser.

Comment: will post in 3...2...1

Comment: I could be wrong, but that does not look like the _rendered_ HTML... it looks more like DOM manipulated HTML.  We need to see Browser > View > Source

Comment: And although the Validator uses the `name` attribute, the `id` **matters very much** to your `required: "#newsletter:checked",` and `equalTo: "#password"` rules.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the `id` of your `<form>` is not what you think (look at your rendered code to verify this), your form validation code should be working.

**Working Demo of your code:  http://jsfiddle.net/b3QNY/**

**jQuery**:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#form1').validate();

});
```

**HTML**:

```
<form id="form1">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>A simple comment form with submit validation and default messages</legend>
        <p>
            <label for="cname">Name</label>
<em>*</em>
            <input id="cname" name="name" size="25" class="required"
            minlength="2" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="cemail">E-Mail</label>
<em>*</em>
            <input id="cemail" name="email" size="25" class="required email"
            />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="curl">URL</label>
<em> </em>
            <input id="curl" name="url" size="25" class="url"
            value="" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="comment">Your comment</label>
<em>*</em>
            <textarea id="ccomment" name="comment" cols="22"
            class="required"></textarea>
        </p>
        <p>
            <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: thank you Sparky, but the form validation only works when I use $('form') and not the form ID...And I checked and rechecked my ID...Also, I caanot seem to get the password validation there. Any help there? I am using  https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation -  and I replaced all the html controls with my asp controls, but only the password one is not working...

Comment: @DavidVanStaden, I don't see anything about `password` in your OP.  As far as the `id`,  `.validate()` just needs a valid jQuery selector in order to initialize the form.  If your `id` is not working, then it must not be correct.  Are you looking at the form's `id` in the _rendered_ HTML?  As you can see by my jsFiddle demo, your code should work.

Comment: I will update my answer, I got the whole thing to work, except for the password validator. For some reason, when passing the <input name=password type=password/> to a asp:textbox, it does not work, but it does work for all other elements such as the email...why is that?

Comment: @DavidVanStaden, I see no `id` inside there and yet you've used an `id` to target it within your `equalTo` rule.

Comment: @DavidVanStaden, as already explained, JavaScript/jQuery is only looking at the `client-side` code.  In other words, all that matters to the jQuery is the ***rendered*** HTML code.  **If you're using jQuery to target something, that target selector *must* exist in the rendered HTML in the browser.**

Comment: It does not matter if I use the ID's or not. I removed the email ID and it still works. The ID's in password fields is used only for matching passwords, but the original password length and field checker (to see whether the field is filled in or not)

Comment: Thanks, I see what you mean, but why does <asp:TextBox name="email" type="email" .../> work but not <asp:TextBox name="password" type="password".../> ?

Comment: @DavidVanStaden, the validate plugin is using the `name` attributes unless you target an `id` like in your `equalTo` rule.  Please stop showing me the ASP code... again, the Validate plugin is only looking for a ***rendered*** field with `name="password"`... does that exist in your ***rendered*** HTML?  **Why not just copy & paste the rendered HTML into your OP?**

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved it - You have to create custom rules for the password textboxes...for some reason the rendering of the asp password textboxes does not work too well:

```
                <%= TextBoxPassword.UniqueID %>: {
                     required: true,
                     minlength: 5

                 },

                <%= TextBoxConfirmPassword.UniqueID %>: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 5,
                    equalTo: "#TextBoxPassword"
                },
```

The form validation now works, except for Visual Studio moaning - It highlights the **:** in red and says:

"Expected Identifier, String or Number"

Would that be a problem?